# Angular 4: Call angular function from a global listner

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this listner:

```
this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mousemove', function(e: MouseEvent){

});
```

And I for example I have a variable, and I want to set it from the listner, like:

```
AVariable:number;

HelloWorld() {
    this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mousemove', function(e: MouseEvent){
        this.AVariable = 5;
    });
}
```

I will the error with this is undefined.
My question is: how I can call a variable/function from the listner?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
'mousemove', function(e: MouseEvent){
```

to

```
'mousemove', (e: MouseEvent)=>{
```

if you use `function` the `this` will refer to the click events instance (not with renderer I guess in this situation)

Old js way of doing this is:

```
HelloWorld() {
    var self = this;
    this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mousemove', function(e: MouseEvent){
        self.AVariable = 5;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `phatoarrow` `=>` instead of calling direct function, this will bind to the scope of `this`.

```
HelloWorld() {
    this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mousemove', (e) => {
        this.AVariable = 5;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `AVariable` is not a member of a typescript class who has `HelloWorld` as a member function, then you should not use **this**. You should just call the variable:

```
this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'mousemove', function(e: MouseEvent){
        AVariable = 5;
});
```

Otherwise, the previous answers are what you need.